# Failed to install laravel/breeze

Tags: laravel-9

I'm getting this error when i trying to install laravel/breeze in a laravel 9 project. I need help to solve it. Thank you !

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravel/breeze ^1.21 -> satisfiable by laravel/breeze[v1.21.0, 1.x-dev].
- laravel/breeze[v1.21.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^10.0 -> found illuminate/console[v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/breeze:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/breeze:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.